# The quadratic equation $x^2=c$ in a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras, division-ring

Let $D$ be a division ring. We denote $D'$ by the derived subgroup of the multiplicative group $D\setminus\{0\}$, that is, the subgroup generated by all the commutators of $D\setminus\{0\}$. For $c\in D',$ does there exist an element $a$ of $D$ such that $a^2=c$? In other words, is the quadratic equation $x^2=c$ solvable for each $c\in D'$?

It is true for $D=\mathbb{H},$ which is the real quaternion division ring. Thanks for all your support.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) understand what $D'$ is; (2) think about quaternion algebras over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Don't confuse the group-theoretic commutator $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ with the ring-theoretic commutator $xy-yx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us analyze the problem in a particular case.

Assume that $D$ has prime degree $p$ over its center $F$. Then it is known that $D'$ is the set of elements of reduced norm $1$.
Assume that $c$ has reduced norm $1$, and $c\notin F$. Since $F[c]$ is a commutative subfield of $D$, its degree over $F$ divides $p$. It cannot be $1$ since $c\notin F$. Hence $F[c]/F$ has degree $p$, and $[F[c]:F]=p$. Assume that there exists $a\in D$ such that $a^2=c$. Once again, $F[a]/F$ has degree $p$ (otherwise $c=a^2\in F$ !). Since $F[c]\subset F[a]$, we get $F[a]=F[c]$. Hence $a\in F[c]$.

So we have to solve the equation $a^2=c$ in $F[c]$. Since $F[c]/F$ is a MAXIMAL commutative subfield of $D$, $Nrd_D(x)=N_{F[c]/F}(x)$ for all $x\in F[c]$.

Hence, we need to solve the equation $a^2=c$ in the field $F[c]$, where $N_{F[c]/F}(c)=1$. However, this equation does not have always solutions.

We can now construct explicit counter examples. Take $D=(d,-1)_\mathbb{Q}$, where $d$ is not a sum of two squares (for example $d$ is a prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$, or negative), so $D$ is division. Let $j\in D$ the basis element such that $j^2=-1$.

Then $Nrd_D(j)=-j^2=1$, so $j\in D'$. Now the above analysis shows that, if $a^2=j$, then $a\in \mathbb{Q}[j]$.

Write $a=x+yj,x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $x^2-y^2+2xyj=j$, so $y=\pm x$ and $2xy=1$. We then get $\pm 2x^2=1\in\mathbb{Q}$, which has no solution.

Of course, you can avoid the general analysis if you only work with this particular example, and I am pretty sure you can prove by hand that $j\in D'$, but I think it is still interesting to know how counterexamples are found...

Comment: Oh, this is a great answer. I wonder if the equation $x^2=c$ is solvable in the projective special linear group $PSL_2(D)$ over a division ring $D.$ It is also true for the real quaternion division ring $\mathbb{H}.$ But in general, I don't know.

Comment: In fact, I need to solve for $c=diag(1,s),$ the $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix in $PSL_2(D)$ with $s\in [D,D].$

Comment: Nope, the same counterexample applies.
 Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. There is an isomorphism $D\otimes_L\simeq M_2(L)$ which sends $j$ to $H=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \cr 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. If your equation has a solution with $s=j$, then the equation $M^2=\begin{pmatrix}I_2 & 0\cr 0 & H\end{pmatrix}$ has a solution in $PSL_4(L)$. In  particular, the equation $M^2=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda I_2 & 0\cr 0 & \lambda H\end{pmatrix}$ has a solution in $SL_4(L)$ for some $\lambda\in L^\times $ such that $\lambda^4=1$.

Comment: Let $N$ the rhs matrix. 
Then $F=\ker(M^2-\lambda I_4)=\ker(N-\lambda I_4)=Span(e_3,e_4)$ is stable by $M$. Taking the corresponding induced endomorphisms on $F$, we get that $\lambda H=\begin{pmatrix}0 & - \lambda \cr \lambda & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is a square in $GL_2(L)$.

If $P=\begin{pmatrix}u & v \cr w & t\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $P^2=\lambda H$, then $P$ commutes with $H$, hence $P$ is a polynomial in $H$ (since $H$ is a companion matrix. You can also derive this by computation). Hence $P=aI_2+b H,$ and $P^2=(a^2-b^2)I_2+2ab H=H$. Hence $b=\pm a$, and $\pm 2 a^2=-1, a \in L$.

Comment: So, if $\pm 2$ are not squares in $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, you reach a contradiction. For example, you can take for $d$ any positive odd number which is is not a sum of two squares, so $D$ is division. $-2$ is not a square in $L$ since in this case, $L$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, and $2$ is not a square in $L$. Otherwise, we would have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, and thus $2d$ should be a square in $\mathbb{Q}$, which is not possible either since $d$ is odd.

Comment: Yes. I understood. Thank you so much @GreginGre.